# make a boolean-like matrix from multiple vectors

Tags: r

Assume

```
xx.1 <- c("a", "b", "d")
xx.2 <- c("a", "d", "e")
xx.3 <- c("b", "e", "d", "f")
```

How to make a boolean matrix as this:

```
xx.1 xx.2 xx.3
a    1    1   NA
b    1   NA    1
d    1    1    1
e   NA    1    1
f   NA   NA    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `table` and `stack`:

```
table(stack(list(xx.1 = xx.1, xx.2 = xx.2, xx.3 = xx.3)))
#       ind
# values xx.1 xx.2 xx.3
#      a    1    1    0
#      b    1    0    1
#      d    1    1    1
#      e    0    1    1
#      f    0    0    1
```

More conveniently, you can try:

```
table(stack(mget(ls(pattern = "xx"))))
```